# OpenTK NotImplementedException tutorial

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, opentk

I am trying to create a Windows Form with an openGL canvas on it, or rather a GLControl so I'm using openTK. Because I'm still new to it, I have decided to try out the following [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138452/An-Analog-Clock-Design-Using-OpenTK-in-Csharp)

It took me a while to find a version which allowed me to add a GLControl to the visual studio toolbox; many different versions gave me an error ("There are no components in C:...\OpenTK.GLControl.dll that can be placed on the toolbox)

Using the current version from the official github finally got that part working for me.

```
private void glControl1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int w = glControl1.Width;
   int h = glControl1.Height;
   glControl1.MakeCurrent();
   GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
   GL.LoadIdentity();
   GL.ClearColor(Color.SkyBlue);
   GL.Ortho(-w / 2, w / 2, -h / 2, h / 2, -1, 1);
   GL.Viewport(0, 0, w, h);
   GL.End();
   glControl1.SwapBuffers();
}
```

however when I implement this from the tutorial inside my form and assign that method to the GLControl in the designer I get a NotImplementedException.
The same goes for the glControl1_Paint (and glControl1_Load)
I have also tried to assign these methods to the form itself instead but it yielded the same error.

The output I get from running the application is

```
'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded  'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Algernon\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AnalogClockTutorial\AnalogClockTutorial\bin\Debug\AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
 'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
 'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
 'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
 'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
 'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
 'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x2c10 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2b70 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Algernon\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AnalogClockTutorial\AnalogClockTutorial\bin\Debug\AnalogClockTutorial.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Algernon\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AnalogClockTutorial\AnalogClockTutorial\bin\Debug\OpenTK.GLControl.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Algernon\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AnalogClockTutorial\AnalogClockTutorial\bin\Debug\OpenTK.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: AnalogClockTutorial.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
GraphicsMode.Default = Index: , Color: 32 (8888), Depth: 16, Stencil: 0,  Samples: 0, Accum: 0 (0000), Buffers: 2, Stereo: False
Detected configuration: Windows / .Net
Loaded opengl32.dll: 1794703360
Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in OpenTK.dll
Creating GraphicsContext.
GraphicsMode: Index: , Color: 32 (8888), Depth: 16, Stencil: 0, Samples: 0,   Accum: 0 (0000), Buffers: 2, Stereo: False
IWindowInfo: Windows.WindowInfo: Handle 4130538, Parent (null)
GraphicsContextFlags: Default
Requested version: 1.0
DisplayDevice 1 (secondary) supports 275 resolutions.
DisplayDevice 2 (secondary) supports 92 resolutions.
DisplayDevice 3 (primary) supports 92 resolutions.
[WGL] Creating temporary context to load extensions
Setting pixel format... [WGL] ChoosePixelFormatARB not supported on this  context
10
OpenGL will be bound to window:4130538 on thread:10
Setting pixel format... Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException'  in OpenTK.dll
```

Does anyone happen to know what's causing this problem and how I should solve it? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the pre-release versions I managed get the GLControl into my toolbox by using the .dll copy inside the bin\debug instead of using the one in the paket folder that's included to the solution upon using NuGet.

**Note: I've copied the OpenTK.dll, OpenTK.dll.Config, and OpenTK.GLControl.dll to the debug folder**

links to the pre-releases:

[OpenTK.GLControl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenTK.Next.GLControl/1.2.2336.6514-pre)

[OpenTK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenTK.Next/1.2.2336.6514-pre)

Installing openTK.GLControl.Next will automatically install OpenTK.Next. Since I could not find the answer very easily I'm posting it here instead of deleting this question.